# Git:Clear all Commits into One commit

Tags: git

I want to clear all the commits and have one commit
i,e., Remove All Commits and have only one commit message with latest commit

I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~4`. And tried squashing all commits except the first one . But this is losing all the latest changes

I just want only latest one commit

[image]

When I checked `git log --oneline` I see that `2cd..f` is my latest commit

[image]

When I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~4` ,I see that my latest commit `2cd..f` is in the last line

When tried to squash all the commits except the last one, I lost all my latest changes .I also tried having only first as pick and all others as squash still I am loosing changes

[image]

Comment: I don't understad, do you want to remove the changes from all commits, except the last one or dou you want to merge all the changes in one commit?

Comment: @JonadGarcíaSanMartín Merge all commit into one commit (latest commit)

Comment: OK, I added one answer, if that doesn't work properly, explain the behavior expected vs the obtained. Greetings!!!

Comment: @JonadGarcíaSanMartín I have updated the Original post with more screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve it

Create a temporary branch and checkout:

`$ git checkout --orphan temp_branch`

Add all files to the temporary branch and commit the changes:

`$ git add -A`

`$ git commit -am "The first commit"`

Delete the Old branch:

`$ git branch -D DS-10292`

Rename the temporary branch to master:

`$ git branch -m master`

Forcefully update the remote repository:

`$ git push -f origin DS-10292`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to commit or stash your latests changes. Then you have to squash with

```
git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits to squash>
```

If the squash does not work properly, see this excellent article:

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-squash/

That will merge the last X commits into one with all the changes.

Comment: I tried the same, Why is the latest commit is in the last instead of in the first when I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~4`

Comment: In interactive rebase, the last (most recent) commit is in the last place of the text editor. That's the way it was designed, so, that doesn't mean that commits were reverted. You just replace "pick" by "s" in all commits except the last one at the editor.